# Meta tags in chrome extension manifest.json?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'll give a contrived example:

Imagine that I wanted to list my Chrome extension on the Chrome Web Store under the title "Brad's Animal Names Extension" but I also wanted my extension to be revealed in the search results for "elephant".

Is there any way I can do this without renaming my extension as "Brad's Animal Names Extension Elephant"?

I was thinking about adding meta-tags in the manifest.json but haven't found any evidence this is possible.

Comment: The Chrome Web Store lets you type a "Detailed Description".  Can't you talk about elephants there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think meta tags are supported, but if you place the keyword in the description field, then that seems to work.

For example:

```
{
  "name": "Brad's animal name extension",
  "description": "Lets you name animals like Elephant and Rhino",
  ...
}
```

Comment: As a side note, do not put something like "tags: tag1, tag2, tag3, tag4..." in your description or detailed description. It is against the terms of service and your extension will be removed from the chrome store